# error: expected ')' before numeric constant

Tags: c, compiler-errors

ERROR: EXPECTED ')' BEFORE NUMERIC CONSTANT

My code seems to be correct but the compiler consistently sends me an error message. After an hour trying to edit and compile, I still can't find the error. Help?
This is my code:

```
void get_record()
{

    char record_num[LEN];
    int x, y;
    printf("Enter the record number of the Student Record to modify: ");
    fgets(record_num, LEN, stdin);
    {
        x = atoi(record_num);
        if (x>STUDENTS||x<=0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-"STUDENTS".\n");
            printf("Enter the record number of the Student Record to modify: ");
            get_record();
        }
    }
    output();
    _z= x;
    i= (x-1);
    printf(LEV2"%3d     %25s    %9s         ", x, name[i], studno[i]);
        for (y=0; y<EXAMS; y++)
            {
            printf("%5s   ", exam_z[y]);
            y++;
            }
}
```

Help?

Comment: copy-paste error messages from compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `STUDENTS` is a string literal (which it isn't because you compare it to an int above) you should include it in a string using a format specifier `%d`, like this:

```
printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-%d.\n", STUDENTS);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the error statement wrong. `STUDENTS` should be a compile time constant since you are using it in `if` condition as well. So,try -

```
printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-%d.\n",STUDENTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-"STUDENTS".\n");
```

you use " " wrong, if you want to put " in string you do \" every time.

Now it should be fine:

```
printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-\"STUDENTS\".\n");
```

Or if you wanted to print out actual value of STUDENTS:

```
printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-%d.\n",STUDENTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-"STUDENTS".\n");
```

should be

```
printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-"+STUDENTS+".\n");
```

Adjacent strings need to be concatenated with the `+` operator.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I'm used to Java/C++, that won't work in C. It's better to use printf as it's intended:

```
printf("ERROR: Invalid Input. Input should be from 1-%d.\n",STUDENTS);
```

See: [printf documentation](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)

Comment: And you're sure about it?